# Drop down list with submit

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, onclick

Very basic question here. I'm trying to make a simple form that includes a dropdown list and a submit button, with each dropdown item corresponding to a pdf file. The user must simply select an item and click "submit" and the file will download.

I accomplished this by adding an `onClick` event to the submit button. HOWEVER, WordPress strips out `onClick` events. How do I accomplish this in the simplest way in a WordPress site? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to hard code your form into a page template in your theme. Here is a great resource for creating custom page templates: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/

If the code is added to the template, then the `onClick` will not be stripped out.